# Can Logstash Work With Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

Has anyone gotten [Logstash](http://logstash.net) working with ruby on rails?

My client is telling to use Logstash for log collector etc. I am using ruby on rails technology. most of the part is almost done. But requirement is to get logs into logstash.

Please let me know Is it possible,how?

Comment: Is is possible in stand-alone ruby?

Comment: I wrote this up recently, http://imnithin.in/logstash_with_rails.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [gist link](https://gist.github.com/1388077) on integrating logstash. Also, there is [logstash-lite](https://rubygems.org/gems/logstash-lite), a ruby gem and the subsequent [github project](https://github.com/logstash/logstash) might shed some light on it if you want to roll your own and not trust the gem

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a gem for the same - [logstasher](https://github.com/shadabahmed/logstasher) . It writes rails logs in a separate file, in pure json format which can be consumed by logstash without any processing.

See my [blog](http://shadabahmed.com/blog/2013/04/30/logstasher-for-awesome-rails-logging) for complete instructions on how to setup Logstash and Kibana